# Can I get VBA error messages in English language?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, language

I'm using MS Excel in the Dutch language. When I get error messages they are also in Dutch. Is there any way to get these messages in the English language?

edit: It's Excel 2010 (MS Office Professional Plus 2010)

Comment: I think the messages depend on the locale of the machine! Go into regional settings, change it to English and see if this helps

Comment: Excel itself is the Dutch version of it, and I think changing the locale is not the right solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @George - It is exactly the correct solution. The VBA error is generated by Excel. You will have to enable the english language in order to get error messages ( even excel error messages ) to appear in english.  Furthermore you don't even say what version.

Answer (score 1):

Within Excel click `File -> Options` (or the Dutch equivalent).

You will now be able to choose `Language` on the left hand list and set `Help Language` to English.

[image]

Comment: this is not working.